# How would I use user input to prompt the user to play different games in java?

Tags: java, input, prompt

I am creating a program for class; the program needs to be able to play 4 games depending on which one the user chooses. If the user chooses game1; then the user would play game1, if the user chooses game2, then the user would play game2 etc..

I am trying to figure out how to create a method depending on which game the user wants to play. For example, if the user wants to play game1, I would create a playGame1 method that has the instructions to play game1.

If there is a better way to make it happen, please let me know, Thanks!

So far i'm trying to get user input which creates an if statement that leads the user to play.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Attendant 
{
        public Attendant()
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String choice = input.next();
            System.out.println( " Which game would you like to play? game1 ; game2 ; game3 ; game4 ");

                    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase ( "game1"))
                    {
                        
                    }
                     if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase ( "game2"))
                    {
                        
                    }
                     if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase ( "game3"))
                    {
                        
                    }
                     if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase ( "game4"))
                    {
                        
                    }
     }
}
```

Comment: Suggestions: 1) consider using `int a = myInput.nextInt();`, to read "1", "2", etc.  2) Consider using a Java [switch/case block](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp).  Finally 3) Code a different class method for each of your different games. Call the method from your "case" block.  ALSO: get rid of your inner "public Attendant()".  Substitute `public static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using switch statements

```
switch (choice) {
    case "game1":
        //gameInstructions go here
        break;
    ...
    default:
        //this will be used when user will provide invalid input (like for ex. "gaem1" (mistype)
}
```

this code above will handle your user's game selection, remember to put `break;` to stop   code going further than you want.